# Javascript Some Method nested in For

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

The code below I am trying to see if one of the CrmRoles is in the list of rolesToVerify but I keep getting "undefined" for **roleToVerify** when I walk  through it.

```
const rolesToVerify = ["System Administrator", "Payroll"]

function userHasOneOrMoreRoles(currentUserRoles: CrmRole[], rolesToVerify: String[]) {
    for (let currentUserRole of currentUserRoles) {
        return rolesToVerify.some(roleToVerify =>
           currentUserRole.Name === roleToVerify);
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into repl.it and it's not even valid syntax

Comment: You have a parameter `rolesToVerify` with the same name as the global variable.

Comment: This looks more like TypeScript than Javascript.

Comment: Please provide how you're calling `userHasOneOrMoreRoles`. `rolesToVerify` being defined twice should not make a difference, since it's in two different scopes (though it would be cleaner with different names). What might be happening is `userHasOneOrMoreRoles` is not being called properly.

Comment: Also, see if `console.log(roleToVerify)` also logs undefined, and that it's not an issue with TypeScript transpilation.

Comment: how do you call `userHasOneOrMoreRoles()`? do you pass a second argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning inside a loop, independant of any condition or anything. There's no way, your loop gets past the first iteration.

```
//And you can shorten
rolesToVerify.some(roleToVerify => currentUserRole.Name === roleToVerify);
//to
rolesToVerify.includes(currentUserRole.Name);
```

so either

```
function userHasOneOrMoreRoles(currentUserRoles: CrmRole[], rolesToVerify: String[]) {
    for (let currentUserRole of currentUserRoles) {
        if(rolesToVerify.includes(currentUserRole.Name))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or

```
function userHasOneOrMoreRoles(currentUserRoles: CrmRole[], rolesToVerify: String[]) {
    return currentUserRoles.some(currentUserRole => rolesToVerify.includes(currentUserRole.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems.
First, you are probably calling your function incorrectly cause for me it's partially working.

Second, there is a logical problem in your code: when you iterate over currentUserRoles array you do the `return` after the first iteration (the rest of the elements except the first one will be ignored).

Here's how it should look in my humble opinion:

```js
const rolesToVerify = ["System Administrator", "Payroll"];

type CrmRole = { Name: string };

function userHasOneOrMoreRoles(currentUserRoles: CrmRole[], rolesToVerify: String[]) {
  for (let currentUserRole of currentUserRoles) {
    let roleExists =  rolesToVerify.some(roleToVerify => currentUserRole.Name === roleToVerify);

    if (roleExists) {
      return roleExists;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns false
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}, {Name: 'cow'}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns false
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: rolesToVerify[0]}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns true
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}, {Name: rolesToVerify[0]}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is whether two sets have an intersection – only, you don't care about the particular intersecting values in this situation – you only care if some element in set X matches some element in set Y

Also this is tagged with functional programming, so we use expressions instead of statements

```
// hasIntersection :: ([a], [a]) -> Boolean
const hasIntersection = (xs = [], ys = [], x = 0, y = 0) =>
  y === ys.length
    ? false
    : x === xs.length
      ? hasIntersection (xs, ys, 0, y + 1)
      : xs [x] === ys [y] || hasIntersection (xs, ys, x + 1, y)

console.log (hasIntersection ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])) // false
console.log (hasIntersection ([1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 6])) // true
console.log (hasIntersection ([1, 2, 3], []))        // false
console.log (hasIntersection ([], [4, 5, 6]))        // false
console.log (hasIntersection ([], []))               // false
```

The input arrays can have values of any type – here the roles are integers, but you could use strings or another type you want

Comment: Adelin, most of my answers involve recursion somehow – let me know if can help more ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rolesToVerify = ["System Administrator", "Payroll"];

type CrmRole = { Name: string };

function userHasOneOrMoreRoles(currentUserRoles: CrmRole[], rolesToVerify: String[]) {
  for (let currentUserRole of currentUserRoles) {
    let roleExists =  rolesToVerify.some(roleToVerify => currentUserRole.Name === roleToVerify);

    if (roleExists) {
      return roleExists;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns false
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}, {Name: 'cow'}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns false
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: rolesToVerify[0]}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns true
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}, {Name: rolesToVerify[0]}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns true
```

```js
const rolesToVerify = ["System Administrator", "Payroll"];

type CrmRole = { Name: string };

function userHasOneOrMoreRoles(currentUserRoles: CrmRole[], rolesToVerify: String[]) {
  for (let currentUserRole of currentUserRoles) {
    let roleExists =  rolesToVerify.some(roleToVerify => currentUserRole.Name === roleToVerify);

    if (roleExists) {
      return roleExists;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns false
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}, {Name: 'cow'}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns false
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: rolesToVerify[0]}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns true
console.log(userHasOneOrMoreRoles([{Name: 'horse'}, {Name: rolesToVerify[0]}], rolesToVerify)); // Returns true
```

I actually ended up with the code below, but the return inside the loop was the issue.

```
function userHasOneOrMoreRoles(currentUserRoles: CrmRole[], rolesToVerify: String[]) {
    for (let currentUserRole of currentUserRoles) {
        if (rolesToVerify.some(roleToVerify => currentUserRole.Name === roleToVerify)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```